# SQL hierarchy boolean roll up

Tags: sql, oracle, tree

I have two tables: Data and Data2.  Data has 3 boolean values and Data2 is a link table to show the hierarchy of the data class.  I'm trying to find a query which only shows the roots of Data2, and if any value in that tree has each of the boolean values as true.

**Data Table**

| Name | Atrue | Btrue | Ctrue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| parent1 |  |  |  |
| parent2 |  |  |  |
| child1 | X | X |  |
| child2 |  |  |  |
| child3 |  | X | X |

**Data2 Table**

| parent_id | child_id |
| --- | --- |
| parent1 | child1 |
| parent2 | child2 |
| child2 | child3 |

So in theory I would show

| Name | Atrue | Btrue | Ctrue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| parent1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| parent2 |  | 1 | 1 |

I don't need the count of how many boolens are true, and just saying if any child has a true value, but I can still work with a count if it's easier.

Comment: Please, show your current code and describe what is wrong with it. In case of only one level of hierarchy (parent and child) it can be done with simple join. If the data may contain more than one hierarchy level, then please provide such sample data and desired output for it

Comment: I don't have any working code yet, as this is just a sub-query to a much larger query.  The hierarchy is more than one level.  The example I gave shows one parent with one child, and another parent with 2 levels of children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After joining your relationship table to your table of booleans, you can use `CONNECT BY` to tie the parents to the children. You can also use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` and a `NOT EXISTS` statement to only get top level parents instead of every child in the entire relationship.

### Query

```sql
WITH
    data1 (name,
           atrue,
           btrue,
           ctrue)
    AS
        (SELECT 'parent1', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'parent2', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'child1', 'X', 'X', NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'child2', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'child3', NULL, 'X', 'X' FROM DUAL),
    data2 (parent_id, child_id)
    AS
        (SELECT 'parent1', 'child1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'parent2', 'child2' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'child2', 'child3' FROM DUAL)
  SELECT parent_name,
         MAX (atrue)     AS atrue,
         MAX (btrue)     AS btrue,
         MAX (ctrue)     AS ctrue
    FROM (    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT d2.parent_id     AS parent_name,
                     d1.atrue,
                     d1.btrue,
                     d1.ctrue
                FROM data2 d2 JOIN data1 d1 ON d2.child_id = d1.name
          CONNECT BY d2.parent_id = PRIOR d2.child_id)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT 1
                FROM data2
               WHERE child_id = parent_name)
GROUP BY parent_name
ORDER BY parent_name;
```

### Result

```
   PARENT_NAME    ATRUE    BTRUE    CTRUE
______________ ________ ________ ________
parent1        X        X
parent2                 X        X
```

Comment: Better to run the hierarchical query first, and only then join to the truth values. There is no need for the "connect by" engine to carry along the truth values (which it must do if we join first). Also, the `start with` clause would save you some work in the hierarchical query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
with
  h (name, descendant) as (
    select  connect_by_root(parent_id) as name, child_id
    from    data2
    start   with parent_id like 'parent%'  --  adapt as needed
    connect by   parent_id = prior child_id
  )
select h.name, max(d.atrue) as atrue, max(d.btrue) as btrue, max(d.ctrue) as ctrue
from   h left outer join data d on h.descendant = d.name
group  by h.name
;

NAME     ATRUE  BTRUE  CTRUE
-------  -----  -----  -----
parent2         X      X    
parent1  X      X
```

First run a straight hierarchical query ("connect by") and mark the root ("parent") for each child. Then join to the truth table, and aggregate over roots ("parents"). I used a left outer join for the possibility that a child in the hierarchical table doesn't appear at all in the truth table (interpreting that as "all columns are null for that child). In the hierarchical query, in the `start with` clause, I assumed the root names begin with `'parent'` - that is not a good practice, a better one would be to have rows where the "parent" appears as child, with their parent shown as `null`. (You may also `start with parent_id not in (select child_id from data2)` - this will cause `data2` to be scanned twice.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query that starts with the valid children and work back to the roots (which, reversing the path through the hierarchy would be the leaves):

```sql
SELECT d.name,
       MAX(CONNECT_BY_ROOT atrue) AS Atrue,
       MAX(CONNECT_BY_ROOT btrue) AS Btrue,
       MAX(CONNECT_BY_ROOT ctrue) AS Ctrue
FROM   data d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Data2 r
       ON (d.name = r.parent_id)
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH
       Atrue IS NOT NULL
OR     Btrue IS NOT NULL
OR     Ctrue IS NOT NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR d.name = r.child_id
GROUP BY d.name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Data (Name, Atrue, Btrue, Ctrue) AS
SELECT 'parent1', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
SELECT 'parent2', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
SELECT 'parent3', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
SELECT 'parent4', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
SELECT 'parent5', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
SELECT 'child1',  'X',  'X',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child2',  NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child3',  NULL, 'X',  'X'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child4',  NULL, NULL, 'X'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child5',  NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child6',  NULL, 'X',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child7',  NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child8',  NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Data2 (parent_id, child_id) AS
SELECT 'parent1', 'child1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'parent2', 'child2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'parent3', 'child4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'parent3', 'child5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'parent5', 'child7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child2',  'child3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child5',  'child6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'child7',  'child8' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | ATRUE | BTRUE | CTRUE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | parent2 | *null* | X | X |
> | parent1 | X | X | *null* |
> | parent3 | *null* | X | X |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f236589a02ef2a42c3609ab0b7c8242c)*